# SNMPTT No access configuration - dropping trap

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp

I have a host server that has its own MIB file, but I need to be able to catch the MIB traps on Nagios 4.1 core. I'm using the SNMPTT plugin installed on a RedHat 6.5, but I'm not able to get my traps inside my SNMPTT.

I generate snmp events `./simulate_events_tf.sh` (on my monitored host)

Content of `tail /var/log/messages`

```
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.  
Sep 18 12:33:02 gdl-storage snmptrapd[32621]: No access configuration - dropping trap.
```

`/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf`:

```
# Example configuration file for snmptrapd'

# No traps are handled by default, you must edit this file!

disableAuthorization yes

#authcommunity log,execute,net public       

#traphandle default /usr/sbin/snmptt

traphandle default /usr/sbin/snmptthandler

# traphandle SNMPv2-MIB::coldStart /usr/bin/bin/my_great_script col
```

Comment: I tried commenting #disableAthorization yes and uncommeting authcommunity log,execute,net public on the file                           /etc/snmp/snmptrap.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get an error when running

```
snmptrapd -f -Lo
```

Your error is probably something like this

```
Warning: no access control information configured.
    (Config search path: /usr/local/etc/snmp:/usr/local/share/snmp:/usr/local/lib/snmp:/root/.snmp) This receiver will *NOT* accept any incoming notifications.
```

It might be that the conf file you edited is not on that path.
In that case copy `/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf` to a path from the error message.

It worked for me a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 6):

I've resolve this issue :

```
vim /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf:



disableAuthorization yes
```